# How can the runtime efficiency of this function be improved?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, runtime

I am trying to write optimal code (good runtime efficiency) for removing duplicate words in a sentence.

For example the input string `Jack Juliet Juliet Jill Jack Romeo Jack Jill` to the function should return `Jack Juliet Jill Romeo`

The following is my code :

```
std::string removeDuplicateWords(const std::string& str)
{
    std::stringstream ss (str);
    std::unordered_set<std::string> string_history;
    std::string current_string, output_string;
    ss >> current_string;
    string_history.insert(current_string);
    output_string += current_string;
    while(ss >> current_string) {
        if(string_history.find(current_string) == string_history.end()) {
            output_string += " " + current_string;
            string_history.insert(current_string);
        }
    }
    return output_string;
}
```

Comment: Using `std::move` on each insert will likely be great. You could also change `output_string` to a `stringstream` also and then return `output_string.str()`.

Comment: I think for better readability you should, at least, use <algorithm> header. Also I suggest you to look at range-v3 library. Views can done it lazily so you might gain performance improvement.

Comment: @DeiDei why change `output_string` to a `stringstream`? Then you're going to have to copy its buffer.

Comment: To answer this kind of question, your starting point should be to give your program the kind of input you're trying to optimise for (for example, a large number of words) and run it under a profiler. That will show you where the time is being spent, if that's what you're optimising for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, gaining performance doesn't make much sense, if you only have about 10 words to process, use the easier code. However, there are some things you can do to improve performance.

First of all, you don't want to check check if an element is in the set. `insert` returns you a pair of iterator-bool, where the first is the iterator to the element with the key (either existing or new) and the second is a Boolean that indicates if an insert happened.

```
      if (string_history.insert(current_string).second)
          output_string += " " + current_string;
```

This both simplifies code and improves performance. As already indicated in comments, using`std::move` makes sense, however, if you use it with insert, you need the iterator to get a hold of the moved to object.
For this case, it won't help, as you are in the SSO cases.

A second thing that requires more code, is to remove `std::stringstream`. Streams give some overhead. Instead, you can better accept a `std::string_view` and use substring logic to cut it into pieces. This prevents the creation of new string objects and removes overhead from streams. You do need C++17 (or a library providing this).

Finally, you can reserve `output_string` at the beginning, you know the maximum size (aka size of str). This can prevent reallocations if you end up out of the SSO range.

Answer (score 0):

**Improvements:**

- You don't need to check whether the string exists because unordered_set does it for you.
- current_string is moved, because we no longer need it.

  ```
  std::string removeDuplicateWordsImproved( const std::string& str )
  {
      std::stringstream ss (str);
      std::unordered_set<std::string> string_history;
      std::string current_string, output_string;

      while( ss >> current_string )
          string_history.insert( std::move( current_string ) );

      for ( auto& word : string_history )
          output_string.append( std::move( word ) ).push_back( ' ' );

      output_string.erase( output_string.size() - 1 );

      return output_string;
  }
  ```

Comment: Unlike the original, you reorder the output, instead of keeping it stable compared to the input.

Comment: Yes, you are right i assume that it is not a problem.

Comment: If reordering is a problem then @JVApen's answer could be preferred.

Comment: The order of the output string must be the same as the input string